# How does encryption in Chrome VPN (proxy) extensions work?

Tags: encryption, google-chrome-extension, proxy, vpn

I need to build a Chrome VPN (proxy) extension. I've been reading about the chrome.proxy API, checking other extensions' code, and made a few examples with a NodeJS proxy.

But I don't understand how the existing VPN extensions in the Web Store encrypt the data. For example: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zenmate-free-vpn%E2%80%93best-vpn/fdcgdnkidjaadafnichfpabhfomcebme (ZenMate VPN).

They say: "We use TLS 1.2 (RFC 5246) protocol and support different cipher suites with PFS (Perfect Forward Secrecy). Our browser extensions use AES 128-bit encryption, and our desktop & mobile clients use AES 256-bit." (https://zenguard.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201259141-What-kind-of-encryption-is-ZenMate-using-is-it-secure-)

From this answer (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1476/what-is-the-difference-in-security-between-a-vpn-and-a-ssl-connection) I've found this: "Some VPN implementations actually use SSL".

So I'm wondering what kind of encryption do Chrome VPN extensions use? Do they simply send all the traffic via https to their servers, which results in double encryption for https and single encryption for http? Or can Chrome extension use some other type of encryption (which as I understand some desktop VPNs use [however I may be incorrect here, since I don't know a lot of the details of how VPNs work])?

Comment: There are various chrome extension downloaders on the web. You can download the crx file, rename it to a zip, extract the contents and simply read the source code. It will be minified or obfuscated but usually you can get an idea how they are doing it.